# Kafka streams via Spring functional def - misconfigured

Tags: java, spring-kafka

1. In my application.yml Im getting a message from IJ that `cloud.stream.function.definition` isn't defined.
2. When I start the app I get this error `Invalid topology: Topology has no stream threads and no global threads, must subscribe to at least one source topic or global table`

I have this defined:

```
@Configuration
@EnableKafka
@EnableKafkaStreams
public class Config {
...

@Bean
Consumer<KStream<String, String>> streamConsumer() {
... }
```

In application.yml I have this:

```
spring: 
  cloud.stream.function.definition: streamConsumer
  cloud.stream.bindings.streamConsumer-in-0.destination: input-topic
  cloud.stream.bindings.streamConsumer-out-0.destination: output-topic
  cloud.stream.bindings.streamConsumer.group: stream-consumer-group
```

It seems like Im missing a dependency but I can't figure out what it is.

Suggestions?

---

If I include this the app starts ok:

```
@Component
public class WordProcessor {

@Autowired
void buildPipeline(StreamsBuilder streamsBuilder) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Dialing back the version of spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka to 3.0.13.RELEASE and restating the @Bean as

```
@Bean
KStream<String, String> streamConsumer(StreamsBuilder streamsBuilder) {
```

seems to have done the trick. Im guessing this process has been redefined in recent builds but the docs / support haven't caught up.